# The tbl_summary function does not appear to handle filtered data properly

Tags: gtsummary

My data contains a column called 'Disease_subtype ' and the entries in the column is one of the following numbers:  0, 1, 2, 3, 4.  I filtered out entries of 0 and 4 and tried to show summary of entries of 1, 2, and 3 only. It did not work as I intended and the 0 and 4 entries showed up as NA in the summary.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0it5.png)

```
I wanted to show summary table of entries of 1, 2, and 3 using the following code:
table0 <-
df.wide.paired.filtered %>% 
    filter(Disease_subtype == 1 | Disease_subtype == 2 | Disease_subtype == 3) %>%
    tbl_summary(include = c(Sex, Age, Disease_subtype, EDSS, MS_Tx, T25FW, HPT, domHPT, nondomHPT, 
                            LCVA, SDMT, PASAT),
              by = Disease_subtype) %>%
    add_p() %>% 
    bold_labels()
table0
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCJAs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your by variable, `by = Disease_subtype`, is a factor, and the `tbl_summary()` function purposefully shows all levels of a factor level. If you do not want them to appear in the table, you can add `mutate(Disease_subtype = factor(Disease_subtype))` after your `filter()` and this will remove unobserved factor levels.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Just to bring up an alternative way to Daniel Sjoberg's, you can also use `%>% droplevels()`

EDIT:

```
df.wide.paired.filtered %>% 
    filter(Disease_subtype %in% 1:3) %>% 
    droplevels() %>%
    tbl_summary(include = c(Sex, Age, Disease_subtype, EDSS, MS_Tx, T25FW, HPT, domHPT, nondomHPT, 
                            LCVA, SDMT, PASAT),
              by = Disease_subtype) %>%
    add_p() %>% 
    bold_labels()
```